# How can I make a material for jam?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Well, I thought of something like this: 
[image]

But I couldn't figure out, how to achieve a similar material.
I messed around with the nodes and that's how my material looks like:
[image]

Can someone help me? -Thanks, beforehand.

(Sorry for my English, but I'm Austrian.)

Comment: In general it is better to attempt it yourself first and then come back here when you have reached the limits of what you can do.

Comment: Can you add a few more reference images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out, you have an unconnected socket shader socket in your node tree.

Anyway maybe mix a little translucent shader into your glass one. You setup looks quite good to me already, much of the remaining work needed is probably pertaining to setting up a proper scene and environment. "Jam in the void" will never look like proper jam.

You might optionally also want to add a particle system to your jam object to simulate the seeds in suspension.

[image: Cycles Jam]

Comment: Jamming in the void could be very dangerous

Comment: is the jam a different object with particle system? that's right?

Comment: Yes, they are is a separate objects, but. It could also be set up in a single object if needed.